# What is the chance of exactly 15 pairs of red and blue balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, balls-in-bins

I have $20$ blue balls and $25$ red balls. All of the $45$ balls are randomly placed in a row. The blue and red balls form a pair when there is a red ball left from a blue ball. If the first ball is a blue ball on the first spot and a red ball on the last spot, then it also counts as a pair. What is the probability that there are exactly $15$ pairs?

I tried dividing the problem into 4 categories:

1. b.....b ,
2. r.....r,
3. r.....b,
4. b....r,

With the first $3$ categories, you still need to make $15$ more pairs and with the last category you need to make only $14$ more pairs. Then I tried to find the number of possible ways to make exactly $15$ more pairs in the first three categories, but I got stuck on how to do that.
I also know that the probability is equal to the probability of the row consisting of exactly $15$ groups of blue balls and $15$ groups of red balls.

To make $15$ groups of blue balls and $15$ groups of red balls I first need $14$ red balls to divide my $15$ groups of blue balls, then I need $14$ blue balls to divide my $15$ groups of red balls. Now there are $45 - 14 - 14 = 17$ balls left, $6$ blue balls and $11$ red balls. Then there are $C(17,6) \cdot C(17,11)$ possible combinations? I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: First I divided into 4 categories:

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. `...First I divided into 4 categories...` Please add your attempt in the body of the question instead of commenting.

Comment: 1. b.....b ,
2.r.....r, 
3.r.....b, 
4.b....r, 
with the first 3 categories you still need to make 15 more pairs and with the last category you need to make only 14 more pair. Then I tried to find the number of possible ways to make exactly 15 more pairs in the first three categories, but I got stuck on how to do that...
I also know that the probability is equal to the probability of the row consisting of exactly 15 groups of blue balls and 15 groups of red balls.

Comment: Do you mean a pair if formed when we have the substring $rb$ or there is a blue ball at the left end and a red ball at the right end?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I mean a pair is formed when we have the substring rb.

Answer (score 2):

There are a total of 
$$\binom{45}{20}$$
sequences that can be formed with $20$ blue and $25$ red balls.

A *run* is a sequence of one or more balls of the same color.

If there are $15$ transitions from red to blue, then we have the following possibilities:

1. The first ball is red, and there are $15$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls.
2. The first ball is red, and there are $16$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls.
3. The first ball is blue, and there are $16$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls.
4. Since the runs are allowed to wrap around so that having a blue ball in the first position and a red ball in the last position counts as a red-blue pair, we could also have a sequence which the first ball is blue, and there are $15$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls.

*The first ball is red, and there are $15$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls*:  Let $r_i$ be the number of red balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + \cdots + r_{15} = 25$$
is an equation in the positive integers.

A particular of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in the $n - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $n$ ones.

To illustrate, suppose that $k = 4$ and $n = 10$.  Then we wish to place three  addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
If we pick the third, fifth, and seventh spaces, we obtain
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 3$.

The number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$ corresponds to the number of ways we can place $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, which is
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
which we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $n - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row with $n$ ones will be filled with addition signs.

Therefore, there are 
$$\binom{25 - 1}{15 - 1}$$
ways to have $15$ runs of red balls.

Let $b_i$ be the number of blue balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots + b_{15} = 20$$
is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{20 - 1}{15 - 1} = \binom{19}{14}$$
solutions.

Thus, there are 
$$\binom{24}{14}\binom{19}{14}$$
sequences beginning with a red ball in which there are $15$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls.

*The first ball is red, and there are $16$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls*:  Let $r_i$ be the number of red balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 16$.  Then
$$r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + \cdots + r_{16} = 25$$
is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{25 - 1}{16 - 1} = \binom{24}{15}$$
solutions.

Let $b_i$ be the number of blue balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots + b_{15} = 20$$
is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{20 - 1}{15 - 1} = \binom{19}{14}$$
solutions.

Thus, there are 
$$\binom{24}{15}\binom{19}{14}$$
sequences beginning with a red ball in which there are $16$ runs of red balls and $15$ runs of blue balls.

*The first ball is blue, and there are $16$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls*:  Let $b_i$ be the number of blue balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 16$.  Then
$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots + b_{16} = 20$$
is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{20 - 1}{16 - 1} = \binom{19}{15}$$
solutions.

Let $r_i$ be the number of red balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + \cdots + r_{15} = 25$$
is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{25 - 1}{15 - 1} = \binom{24}{14}$$
solutions.

Thus, there are 
$$\binom{19}{15}\binom{24}{14}$$
sequences beginning with a blue ball in which there are $16$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls.

*The first ball is blue, and there are $15$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls*:  Let $b_i$ be the number of blue balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \cdots + b_{15} = 20$$
is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{20 - 1}{15 - 1} = \binom{19}{14}$$
solutions.

Let $r_i$ be the number of red balls in the $i$th run, where $1 \leq i \leq 15$.  Then
$$r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + \cdots + r_{15} = 25$$
is an equation in the positive integers with 
$$\binom{25 - 1}{15 - 1} = \binom{24}{14}$$
solutions.

Thus, there are 
$$\binom{19}{14}\binom{24}{14}$$
sequences beginning with a blue ball in which there are $15$ runs of blue balls and $15$ runs of red balls.

*Total*:  Since these four cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{24}{14}\binom{19}{14} + \binom{24}{15}\binom{19}{14} + \binom{19}{15}\binom{24}{14} + \binom{19}{14}\binom{24}{14}$$

Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{24}{14}\dbinom{19}{14} + \dbinom{24}{15}\dbinom{19}{14} + \dbinom{19}{15}\dbinom{24}{14} + \dbinom{19}{14}\dbinom{24}{14}}{\dbinom{45}{20}}$$